# Blackberry connecting to a remote mySql DB

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I am looking at developing an application (in the Blackberry JDE) that has the need to read from a remote mySql database.

Previously, I have added data to mySql databases by sending data to a php script via post. However I am now looking for a solution to connect to a hosted database, execute simple queries and render the returned data in some way shape or form upon the device.

Can anyone point me into the correct direction? Or even better provide me with a basic example of reading data from a mysql db and rending the data upon the device?

(I wish it was as easy as php!)

Many thanks

Comment: i think using php service is best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Blackberry can make an HTTP connection then you can do everything else on the server side in the normal way.  I.e. create some php pages, and browse those to collect the data you need in whatever format you want to return.

Or do you mean that you are not able to make an HTTP connection, and you need to connect to the MySQL server directly?

Comment: you need to do json parsing or xml parsing